# Button Error in Eclipse for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, button

I am working with a database in sqlite that uses two buttons and an EditText field to retrieve user input and display the corresponding record in the database.  I have an error with one of my buttons and I"m not sure what is causing it and I've tried to implement various lines of code and cleaning and am hoping someone could shed a little bit of light as to what is causing the issue. The error that I am getting is that my button cannot be put into a variable. I have put the (*) symbol where the issue is occurring. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
package com.example.database;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class DBUse extends Activity  {
    EditText dEdit;
    SQLiteDatabase data;
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_BUSINESS = "business";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone";
    public static final String KEY_HOURS = "hours";
    public static final String KEY_WEB = "website";
    public static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MainActivity datab = new MainActivity(this);

        Button buttonName =(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonName);
        buttonName.setOnClickListener(startName);

        **Button buttonType =(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonType);
        buttonType.setOnClickListener(startType);**

        dEdit =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        datab.open();


        Cursor c = datab.getAllTitles();
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{DisplayTitle(c);
        }while (c.moveToNext());
    }   
        datab.open();
        Cursor b = datab.getAllTitles();

        if (b.moveToFirst())
            DisplayTitle(b);
        else
            Toast.makeText(this,"No business found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        data.close();

    data.close();


    }



//displays the data

    public void DisplayTitle(Cursor c)  {
        Toast.makeText(this,
        "Name: " + c.getString(1)+"\n"+
        "Address:" + c.getString(2)+"\n"+
        "Phone:" + c.getString(3)+"\n"+
        "Hours:" + c.getString(4)+"\n"+
        "Website"+ c.getShort(5)+
        "Type" + c.getShort(6),
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

    //Informs the user what is being searched
    private OnClickListener startName=new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick (View v) {

            Cursor cur=data.rawQuery("SELECT business,address,phone,hours,website,type FROM Business where name like %"+dEdit.getText().toString()+"%", null);
            String result="";

            int iRow=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
            int iName=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_BUSINESS);
            int iAddress=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_ADDRESS);
            int iPhone=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONE);
            int iHours=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_HOURS);
            int iWebsite=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_WEB);
            int iType=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_TYPE);
            Toast.makeText(DBUse.this, "Searching by Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //  log.d("result",DBUse.getString(0));
            for(cur.moveToFirst(); !cur.isAfterLast(); cur.moveToNext()){
                result=result +cur.getString(iRow) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iName) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iAddress) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iPhone) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iHours) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iWebsite) + " "
                    +cur.getString(iType) + " " + "\n";

            }
            return;
        };




        //Informs the user what is being searched
        **private OnClickListener startType=new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick (View v){
            Cursor cur=data.rawQuery("SELECT business,address,phone,hours,website,type FROM Business where type like %"+dEdit.getText().toString()+"%", null);**
            String result="";
            int iRow=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
            int iName=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_BUSINESS);
            int iAddress=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_ADDRESS);
            int iPhone=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONE);
            int iHours=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_HOURS);
            int iWebsite=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_WEB);
            int iType=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_TYPE);
            Toast.makeText(DBUse.this, "Searching by Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //  log.d("result",DBUse.getString(0));
            for(cur.moveToFirst(); !cur.isAfterLast(); cur.moveToNext()){
                result=result +cur.getString(iRow) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iName) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iAddress) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iPhone) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iHours) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iWebsite) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iType) + " " + "\n";


            }
            return;
        }


        };
    };
}
```

Problem error message:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
startType cannot be resolved to a variable  DBUse.java  /database/src/com/example/database  line 43 Java Problem
```

Comment: please share your LogCat

Comment: There's nothing in the logcat? but here is the problem from the problems window

Comment: Not sure what you really are doing but this code `MainActivity datab = new MainActivity(this);` indicates that "bad, bad design" is happening there

Comment: If Eclipse marks that line with error mark, hover your mouse over it and tell what is the error message

Comment: What do you mean by bad design?

Comment: the error message I put in an edit that says "startType cannot be resolved to a variable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you are declare the `OnClickListener startType` inside your `OnClickListener startName`. I think it should be two different methods.

Comment: Thanks to @Alex Chengalan I was missing a ";" after my startName method was over this was keeping the second method  startType from being created. Thank you for pointing that out